# How to handle Apostrophe in Strings in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have the following piece of code :

```
public String createDownloadLink(String user) {
    String url = "No file exists";
    String fileName = "download.zip";

    if (userExists())
        url = "<a onClick= 'downloadfile(\"" + user + "\", \"" + Encode.forJavaScript(fileName) + "\")' href='#' >Download</a>";

    return url;
}
```

In the above piece of code, the user value is their respective email address.
This code works fine for all email addresses except for email addresses having an apostrophe in it.

Example : For user = "john.d'cruz@java.com" , the url I get in response is

```
<a onclick="downloadfile("john.d" cruz@java.com", "download.zip")' href="#">Download</a>
```

And this is a broken url so the download fails.

I tried using

```
user = user.replace("'","\'");
```

But it still gives me the same error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `Encode.forJavaScript()` for `user` as well?

Comment: You're not escaping `user`, but why create view-layer stuff in raw Java at all?

Comment: Try this:
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
....
url = String.format("<a onClick=\"downloadFile('%s', '%s')\" href=\"#\" >Download</a>", StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(user), fileName);

Comment: @Ivar Using `Encode.forJavaScript()` for email seems to be working alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need to escape the ' with a \, right?
If so, your method for escaping the ' sign should look like this instead.

```
user = user.replace("'","\\'");
```

Java uses \ for escaping characters, so in your method you were saying ' should be replaced with an escaped ' which basically translates back to the '. Please correct me if I understood the question incorrectly.

Comment: Actually, the explanation is a bit different. The apostrophe has a special meaning. To tell a Java application that the apostrophe in a String should be interpreted as a literal character, you must escape it with the slash character. However, in a String you must also escape the slash so it is NOT interpreted as a literal character. That's why you need the double slash. I still upvoted your answer because I understood what you tried to say. Just edit your question and explain it correctly.

Comment: @hfontanez In Java an apostrophe is an apostrophe, it needs no escaping. The issue is in the JavaScript: the OP needs to escape the string for *JavaScript* string literals.

Comment: @DaveNewton you are absolutely right!!!! I brain-farted. I was thinking about the quotes, not the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

For escaping characters you could use:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("john.d'cruz@java.com");
```

which results in `john.d\'cruz@java.com`.

Add below dependency to your project:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text

and this import statement:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
```

Something like this should work in your case:

```
public String createDownloadLink(String user) {
    if (userExists()) {
       return String.format("<a onClick=\"downloadFile('%s', 'download.zip')\" href=\"#\" >Download</a>", StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(user));
    } 

    return "No file exists";
}
```

Comment: (Delta probably better to use the JS escaper since the issue is the JS rendering.)